# Limit of a function with alternating sign

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If I want to determine the following limit

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{(-1)^k \cdot \arctan(kx)}{\sqrt{k}} $$

does it matter that there is an alternating minus sign? or can I say that when $k \rightarrow \infty$ the denominator becomes very large and the limit is therefore $0$?
It feels like I'm mixing up sequence of functions and series!

Comment: $ | \frac{(-1)^k \cdot \arctan(kx)}{\sqrt{k}} |\leq \frac {\pi} 2 \frac 1  {\sqrt k}$.

Comment: Also be careful when it comes to series. Your reasoning that you used for your example doesn't always apply. Famous counterexample is the harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}.$ Yes, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}=0,$ but  $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}=\infty$ ! But note if $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^k a_n$ exists, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=0.$ In other words, if an infinite series converges, its summand converges to $0$, but the converse is false.

Answer (score 1):

Your limit is in the form:
$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$$
Where $z_0\in \mathbf{R}\cup {\pm \infty}$ and $f(z)$ is a limited function.

Namely:
$$\left |f(k)\right | = \left|\arctan(kx)\right|\leq \frac {\pi} 2 $$

So, because $g(k)\to +\infty$ when $k\to +\infty$, your limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If $\lbrace a_k \rbrace_{k \in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb R$ such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} |a_k|=0,$ then what can you say about the limit $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} a_k$ itself ?

Now, does this apply to your specific example ?